# C++ send compressed html via socket to browser

Tags: c++, sockets, webserver, gzip

I am building web server. I want to send gzipped html page but something is wrong with my code:

```
...
char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
"Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n"
"Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
"Server: michal\r\n"
"Set-Cookie: nazwa=test\r\n"
"Date: Mon, 24 Feb 2014 11:39:26 GMT\r\n"
"Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n\r\n";
std::string body =
"<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>"
"<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>"
"<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>"
"<form method='post' action='/' enctype='multipart/form-data' ><input type='file' name='pliczek1'/><input type='submit' name='sub' value='sender' /><input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='100001_used' ><input type='hidden' name='hidd' value='testowy hiddenik' /><input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='100002_used' ><textarea name='txtform'>tekstowe poleąś</textarea></form>"
"</body></html>\r\n\r\n";

...

std::string responseStr = response;
responseStr += compress_string(body);
std::cout << responseStr;
write(client_fd, responseStr.c_str(), responseStr.length());
close(client_fd);
```

I am using compress_string function: http://pastebin.com/kFGgvVbF
Without compress_string and Content-Encoding everything works fine so, something wrong is with compressing/sending/headers. Page is not loading in browser. In FF displays error with encoding of content. What's wrong ? How to fix it ?

Comment: You neglected to say what the request and response look like.  Do they match up to your expectations?  How do you KNOW that your browser even accepts gzip encoding?  Do you know if that compression routine even outputs proper gzip?

Comment: Browser accept gzip (I see it in headers). How can I check if compression outputs proper gzip ? I want to check it in browser

Comment: Well, one way to do it is to use `gzip` and compare the output.  That compression routine looks pretty sketchy to me.  Might be better to use zlib or something else more mature.

Comment: I found solution ! Content-Encoding must be set to: deflate not gzip ! Thank for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Everything with code is OK but I had to change Content-Encoding header to "deflate" instead of gzipc!